# What is the significance of $A+ (B\cap C)=(A + B)\cap C$, where $A\subseteq C$, for modules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

My book (Introduction to Ring Theory, Paul Cohn) states this as a theorem and gives a proof. The book usually skips over trivial/easy proofs, so I don't really understand why this is in here.

Isn't the statement absolutely obvious for sets $A,B,C$ with $A\subseteq C$? You just need to draw a diagram and it becomes immediately obvious! [image]

Is there a reason why it would not be obvious in modules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if the statement is obvious to you but in general $+$ and $\cap$ don't distribute over each other. I wouldn't expect them to either since $\cap$ is a set theoretic operation and $+$ is only defined for modules/ideals/abelian groups. However, when $A\subset C$ they do distribute over one another.

But the proof *shouldn't* go something like this:

$$A+(B\cap C)=(A+B)\cap (A+C)=(A+B)\cap C $$ where the last equality comes from $A\subset C$ *because* here we assumed they distribute in the first place which is false in general. So any proof of this fact can't use the above method (or the other direction).

---

An explicit example that these operations don't distribute is by taking the submodules of the $\mathbb{Z}[X]$-module $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ where we can now just look at ideals

$A=(2)$, $B=(x-1)$, and $C=(x+1)$
then $$A+(B\cap C)=(2)+(x^2-1)=(2,x^2-1)$$
and $$A+ B \cap A+ C=(2,x-1)\cap(2,x+1)=(2,x+1)$$

since $(2,x-1)=(2,x+1)$.

Comment: I've added a picture of what I meant. If you just draw them as sets and then colour in the relevant parts, you can see that they're the same. This is what I meant by 'obvious'

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt Although instructive, the $+$ operation in your picture is really $\cup$ in which case $\cap,\cup$ do distribute over each other. Essentially you are assuming they distribute over each other (as I say above) which is not true.

Comment: Oh ok, that's what my misunderstanding was, I was reading '+' as 'union', when $A+B$ should actually be the set of all $a+b$ where $a\in A,b\in B$

Comment: Sorry, one more question: why is $B\cap C=6 \mathbb{Z}$? Aren't we looking for the integers which are multiples of both 12 and 30? 6 isn't a multiple of either. Why wouldn't the answer be $60\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt You're right, let me fix the example.

Comment: @man_in_green_shirt Fixed. And completely new!

Comment: Nice example! Although shouldn't there be a $+$ instead of a $\cap$ in the middle part of the first line?

Answer (score 3):

Judging from your diagram, it looks like (?) you are interpreting $+$ as set union. Certainly, if you are working with sets using union and intersection, your picture is accurate.

But using using the $+$ to join submodules of a module does not behave the same way. If $A$ and $B$ are submodules of a module, $A+B$ contains many more elements than just $A\cup B$ in general.

To summarize the situation, the property proved is that the lattice of submodules of a module (join $+$ and meet $\cap$) is a [modular lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_lattice). The lattice of subsets of a set, on the other hand (join $\cup$, meet $\cap$), is also modular, but even more strongly it is a [distributive lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_lattice). In general, the lattice of submodules of a module does *not* have to be distributive.

For more about modularity, let me refer you to a question we had some time ago on the topic: [Why are modular lattices important?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/142214/29335)

Comment: Yes, that was how I was interpreting the '+', when I should have interpreted it as $A+B$ being the set of all $a+b$ where $a\in A, b\in B$. thanks!