# Intuition behind Dedekind's Modular Law

Tags: group-theory, terminology, intuition

Dedekind's Modular Law states :

> Let $G$ be a group and $H, K$ and $L$ be subgroups of $G$ with $K ≤ L$. Then $$\;HK ∩ L = (H ∩ L)K.$$

What is the reason that it is called modular law? Also, what is the intuition behind this theorem?

Comment: This is two separate questions.

Comment: It is a property of meet & join in the ordered structure (=lattice) of sub*modules* of a module over any ring $R$. See [Modular Lattice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_lattice). It crops up, when studying various properties of the submodule lattice. Not unlike the better known parallelogram rule (aka [2nd Isomorphism theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Theorem_B_3)). Observe that it is a bit problematic when viewed as a statement about groups. For the product $HK$ is not always a subgroup.

Comment: In some sense the importance is that this prohibits sublattices isomorphic to [the notorius $N_5$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems#Theorem_B_3). In those lattice diagrams every line corresponds to a simple quotient. Forbidding $N_5$ then is a manifestation of Jordan-Hölder, or the module theoretic analogue of *uniqueness of factorization*.

Comment: I'm not sure those two comments constitute an answer to your question. Needs fleshing out anyway. May be later? Anyway, we probably have more knowledgable users who have used this more recently than I, so ... :-)

Comment: Some intuition: [abstract algebra - Why are modular lattices important? - Mathematics Stack Exchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/142214/why-are-modular-lattices-important/443947#443947)